# Visual Studio 2015 Interactive Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to attach and debug after you have initialized the Interactive Window to your project?

Comment: I'd assume the note in [the current documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window) applies: "The Interactive Window does not currently support any form of debugging".  Maybe it will be different a year from now.

Comment: @JasonH FYI it's not actually at all "messed up" for someone to downvote without commenting. You should expect that to happen with some regularity on this website. There are various discussions on [meta] about it.

Comment: @leppie, Thank you for taking the downvote off.  If I had actually asked how to debug the immediate window, I would have deleted my account immediately and given up on software development all together.  Thank you for the link to the documentation as well.  I have been struggling to find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spite of the documentation saying that debugging isn't supporting you can actually attach the debugger and debug your code (I imagine it might be implying that you can't step through the interactive code or break on it).

All you need to do is go to Debug > AttachToProcess and then browse the list for `InteractiveHost.exe`.  This can be a tad tricky if you're running multiple instances of Visual Studio since there might be a different process for each.  But if you attach the debugger you will definitely hit breakpoints within your own code that you used to initialize the interactive session.

Comment: BRILLIANT!  That does work but I found that when you attach the Interactive Window closes and you have to re-open it after you have started debugging.  Just for anyone else wanting/needing to do this.

Comment: @JasonH Ahh, yeah, I forgot that happens.  That's due to VS having a different window configuration while debugging.  After you've opened it once it should open every time you debug.