# Is it possible to use the c# "interactive window" instead of the immediate window in VS2017

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, read-eval-print-loop

The C# "**interactive** **window**" is more fully featured than the "**immediate** **window**". Is it possible to load the debug context into it during a debug session?

Comment: typo? than the  **interactive** window

Comment: :) Yes. That is correct. Thanks

Comment: the [other way round](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978166/visual-studio-2015-interactive-window), and here [maybe relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11135855/1132334)

Comment: At a rough guess this will allow you to launch code from the interactive window but when you hit a breakpoint you will only have the context available from the immediate window. Not quite what I am looking for though still interesting

Comment: The REPL feature is completely divorced from the debugger interface.  In fact you can't even debug REPL code.  So what you are asking for is simply not possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898123/getting-debugger-context-in-c-sharp-interactive

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106951/1806239

> After you've run Initialize Interactive with Project, you can use
> Debug > Attach to Process to connect to the InteractiveHost.exe
> process.
>
> You can then debug functions from your project.

Works for me in VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using visual studio 2022. In "Debug" mode, click "Debug" menu on top and select "Windows"->"Immediate", an "Immediate Window" will lauch at bottom right(grouped with "Call Stack, Break Points...."), that allows you interact with current context.